# firebase database resets each time I visit the console

Tags: javascript, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Each time I set rules in firebase database console (in the web-page) it resets. Maybe its something I don't get about firebase and saving but I have to set new rules each time I visit the page. I get the "Get Started" page when I go there and I am starting to think that its something I don't get about it. Anyone that can explain what I am not understanding? I have tried to see if things get saved to the database and get an error message:

> "undefined is not an object (evaluating '_firebase.firebase.auth')"

. Maybe thats a separate problem but it could be linked to the above problem. 
Confused...

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import firebase from 'firebase';
import ReduxThunk from 'redux-thunk';
import reducers from './reducers';
import LoginForm from './components/LoginForm';
import Router from './Router';

class App extends Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    const config = {
    apiKey: 'code',
    authDomain: 'domain',
    databaseURL: 'url',
    projectId: 'id',
    storageBucket: 'another url',
    messagingSenderId: 'msgid'
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
}

  render() {
    const store = createStore(reducers, {}, applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk));

    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Router />
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Do you experiment this problem after you have re-deployed your project? For example after deploying from the CLI (`firebase deploy`)?

Comment: What do you mean by deploy firebase? Im new to firebase and programming but im following an online-course on udemy and seem to be the only one with this problem even though I am pretty sure I have taken all the necessary steps... I have also run the firebase installation in my root directory.

Comment: You are probably using the Firebase CLI when you "ran the firebase installation in my root directory.". Do you use the command `firebase deploy` to send your local files to the Firebase platform (for example the index.html page)?

Comment: I updated my question with the code for App.js for you to see. The App.js is what I think you refer to as index.html. Is that the same thing as the deployment?

Comment: How do you deploy the App.js code? You use your terminal window and do `firebase deploy`, don't you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is difficult to be 100% sure what is your problem but you are probably overwriting, upon project deployment, the security rules that you defined in the Firebase console with the ones that are in your local Firebase project.

When you initialise a Firebase project via the CLI (https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/#initializing_a_project_directory) the CLI creates by default a file which contains the database rules (named `database.rules.json`).

When you deploy your project via the `firebase deploy`command (without the `--only` flag), the CLI overwrites the security rules stored in the Firebase online console with the ones you have in this json file.

In order to prevent this behaviour, you can suppress this file in your local project.

Comment: Thanks for your answers! I have one question about firebase database though. When I go in to the console and create a database also specifying rules and publishing them, close down the window, open it again and click on database on the left column I come to "create database" again just like first time even though I never ran the code in my editor. Rules also resets. Is something maybe not right with my account?

Comment: Do you click the "Publish" button on top of the Database Rules editor?

Comment: Strange.... I think I cannot really help you anymore, sorry. Maybe try to create a new project from scratch.

Comment: Ok, I will try doing something. Thanks for your advice and time!

Comment: Just wanted to tell what the problem was, now that I have solved it. I changed import { firebase } from 'firebase'; to import firebase from 'firebase'; and now everything works. I think that the rules does not set until the database have one user at least.

Comment: @iKnowItAll I am facing similar issue and moreover server key also changes itself again and again.